# Move SQL Server 2008 Web Edition

Tags: sql-server-2008, licensing

Ok long story short, at work I've run into the nice situation of having to move our SQL Database from one server to another. We got in touch with our hosting provider and got set up a new server (we needed more memory on the server and couldn't add more to the existing as it was a 32bit one maxed out at 4GB) - now it turns out that I had the EXPRESS version installed, how on earth the guy in there managed to think we'd utilize 10GB of memory with the express edition I do not know.

As we're obviously late with this upgrade I need it done sooner rather than later. Our current license for SQL Server is not something I have been in charge for and I cannot contact anyone that I work with at the moment as I am doing this at night (I live in Europe).

Is there any way I can legally get the software, keys and so forth off of our old server and install the actual Web Edition into the new server? I have administrator acccess and can remote desktop into both of them.

If anyone can help with this I will greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download and install the 180 day [trial](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/trial-software.aspx), then once you get the keys later you can do an in-place "upgrade".

If someone lost the key, you might try looking at the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\XX\Registration->CD_KEY.

I haven't verified the above on a full copy of SQL Server, but found that mentioned a few places on the net (though for SQL 2000, so not sure if it applies).

Comment: I tried that already but couldn't find any. But I can install the trial and run an upgrade (which would be a downgrade i guess as the trial is of enterprise only i think?) easily? and thanks for the help btw

Comment: Yes, see http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/licensing-faq.aspx#upgrades (Q.  How easy is it to migrate from a trial version of SQL Server 2008 to the final purchased product?

A.  

You can upgrade an instance of SQL Server 2008 Evaluation Edition to other editions of SQL Server 2008 without uninstalling Evaluation Edition. For details, see SQL Server 2008 Version and Edition Upgrades.)

Answer (score 0):

Your CoLo should be able to assist you with getting the correct license installed as you are probably renting the license from them.

If not you'll be much better us postponing and doing it correctly the first time and avoiding the second outage when you do the SKUUPGRADE.

Answer (score 0):

A program like  [Belarc Advisor](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html) might be able to find the missing CD key for you:

http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html